# Why did the Vex simulate the future when Atheon is Time's Conflux?

Tags: timeline, destiny

Atheon, Time's Conflux, controls the flow of time throughout the collective Vex mind from inside the Vault of Glass on Venus. The Infinite Forest is a world-sized "computer" capable of incredible simulation software held on Mars, with one of its functions being the simulation of immeasurable amounts of future outcomes for the Vex. Why would they need this prediction software if Atheon could essentially write over any future outcomes by just willing time to bend to its needs? Can Atheon only control the flow of time within the Vault, and not across all Vex space/time?

Considering Atheon's defeat within the Vault was only one possible outcome, it still exists in all other realities created by itself.